# What are the components of a word called?

Tags: etymology, terminology

The etymology of the word *parasol* states that it arises *"from **para**- (“to shield”) + **sole** (“sun”)"*. I would like to know what the two components, *para* and *sole*, are called in this example. Units/components might work. But, I suspect that there is a more fitting linguistic term for them ...

Also, would this term also be applicable for the components of words such as *jaywalk* which is a result of "*jay + walk*"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Within linguistics, the terminology for parts of words varies according to theoretical perspective.  Commonly, though, they are called *morphemes*.

Morphemes are frequently divided into various kinds, most basically, *roots* versus *affixes*.  Roots are “open class” items, like objects (*cat*, *chair*, *paper*) or actions (*run*, *arrive*, *fall*), whereas affixes are “close class” items (such as the verbal endings *ing*, *s*, *ed*). That is to say, within a language, the stock of roots is large and expandable (when you encounter a new animal or invent a new gadget, you can coin a new root), whereas the set of affixes is small(er) and generally fixed (people rarely invent new verbal affixes).

Returning to your question, you can refer to *para*, *sol*, *jay*, and *walk* all as morphemes.  Of these, *para* is an affix, and *sol*, *jay*, and *walk* are roots.  Being a combination of two roots, *jaywalk* is said to be a *compound* (and, given that you can’t derive its meaning from the meanings of its constituent morphemes, it is said to be semantically opaque, or idiomatic).  The root *sol* (also found in *solar*, *solarium*, *solstice*) does not occur in isolation (as a freestanding word *sol*), unlike *jay* and *walk*.  So, it is called a *bound root* (or a *cranberry morpheme*, after the *cran* or *cranberry*, which also does not occur in isolation); *jay* and *walk* are *free roots*.

Comment: +1 for a thorough answer. This ought to become canonical for this topic on this site.

Comment: But are they morphemes *in English* if the word is simply imported wholesale from another language?  To my mind, para- and -sol are not productive English morphemes, however much they may occur in all sorts of words borrowed from Latin, French, or Spanish.

Comment: There is a further division between inflectional and derivational morphemes.

Comment: @librik: ‘Parasol’ has been used in English for 400 years, so I guess that makes it an English word, and both its morphemes are productive of other English words. Are 'parachute' and 'solar' not English words?

Comment: An illuminating explanation. Thanks Daniel :) Quick note: 'Sol' is a name for our star and is also used to represent one day on Mars, a term which we'll hopefully be hearing more of starting tomorrow!

Comment: @coleopterist. Thanks for that. Never knew about the name for the Martian day.

Comment: @Barrie.  Thanks for the comments on the nativization of foreign morphemes.  I agree.

Answer (score 5):

The smallest unit of meaning is called a *morpheme*.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that there is a classification of morphemes called "roots", we're interested in etymology rather than morphology. These word parts are etymological roots in English. But since they have no individual meaning in English (English grammar doesn't let me create a word "paralun" describing a parasol used only at night), they are not morphological roots in English.

To confuse things, English etymological roots are often morphological roots in Latin or other languages.

Comment: So, are you suggesting that it is the 'root' rather than the 'morpheme' that is the basic unit of a word _etymologically_? If we are speaking morphologically, would that mean that there are no semantically opaque (as per Daniel's excellent answer) morphemes for any word?